# A easy way to load a variable from another ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I need a way to be able to include ejs variables from another ejs file. For example:

```
<body>
  <h1> Pre Alpha   -  <%- title %> </h1>
</body>
```

If 'title' is a local variable in the same file it works, but if I want to load it from another file I do not know how to do it.

I tried some of the following ways without success:

data.ejs:

```
   <% var title = 'This is a title'; %>
```

main.ejs

```
<h1> Pre Alpha   -  <%- title %> </h1>
<h1> Pre Alpha   -  <%- data/title %> </h1>
<h1> Pre Alpha   -  <%- data('title') %> </h1>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should try an *include call*.

```
<ul>
  <% users.forEach(function(user){ %>
    <%- include('user/show', {user: user}); %>
  <% }); %>
</ul>
```

http://ejs.co/#docs

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Or have you found something on your side?

Comment: I keep getting the same same user object when i use it for my app, when i console.log it before it shows different ones but after i pass it in to my other ejs file it shows the same object info